# Compare two different lists with a single list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below are the defined variables:

```
l1 = ['20:00,20:01']
l2 = ['20:00']
l3 = ['20:01']
```

Please help, how do i  compare list l2 and l3 values are present in list l1 or not.

Comment: Use `in` operator for every value of `l2` and `l3`.

Comment: You can use `in`, e.g. `l2[0] in l1[0]` will return `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
l1 = ['20:00,20:01']
l2 = ['20:00']
l3 = ['20:01']



if l2[0] in new_list[0]:
     print "l2 in l1"


if l3[0] in new_list[0]:
     print "l3 in l1"
```

You can also combine the expressions:

```
if l2[0] in new_list[0] or l3[0] in new_list[0]:
    print "One list is in l1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
l1 = ['20:00,20:01']
l2 = ['20:00']
l3 = ['20:01']
x = l1[0].partition(',')

l23 = l2 + l3 # merge the two lists l2 and l3
for y in l23:
    print y in x
```